# Unable to Reproduce Ogg Audio in Chrome with Accept-Ranges:Bytes

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, google-chrome, audio

I'm trying to reproduce audio with HTML5, but I'm having problem at time to reproduce Ogg files, this is the configuration in my server (BasicHandler.ashx):

```
        string oggFileName = @"C:\Users\gustav\Desktop\Player\Files\TestAudio.ogg";

        byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(oggFileName);
        httpContext.Response.ContentType = "audio/ogg";
        httpContext.Response.AddHeader("pragma", "Public");
        httpContext.Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
        httpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
        httpContext.Response.Cache.SetLastModified(new DateTime(2000, 01, 01));
        httpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(new DateTime(2020, 01, 01));
        httpContext.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
```

And my player has this code:

```
<div id="Player">
<audio id="audioPlayer" preload="auto" controls onplay="ReloadPlayer()">
    <source src="http://localhost:4677/Services/BasicHandler.ashx" type="audio/ogg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.frff
</audio>
```

The player works perfect with Audio MP3 or MP4 (AAC), but when I try to use Ogg, is not possible play the audio (in Firefox works, but in Chrome is the problem). Any idea of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [table of supported formats at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Audio#.3CAudio.3E_element_format_support).

Comment: In the table says, that Chrome support Ogg since version 9, but with the configuration shown, is not possible.

Comment: By setting the ``Accept-Ranges`` you're telling the client that you are ready to handle range requests, but your code doesn't seem to implement it. This may be the cause. It's unlikely, but I'd give it a shot, so try removing that header.